# Cannot use escape character in batch stript

Tags: batch-file

I have the folowing line in my batch script and try to use dot (".") instead of hypen ("-") between dates. However, while the following is working (with "-"):

```
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
```

when I change to dot ("."), it does not working:

```
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~10,4%
```

I tried several escape character before dots e.g. `\.`, but does not worked. Any idea?

**Update**: Here is the line that uses `TODAY` variable:

```
rar a -r -ep1 %backup%\"%name%_%today%" %folder%
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the code that I use:

```
@echo off

setlocal

REM Specify the folder to compress below:

REM --------------------- Folder to compress -----------------------------------
set dir="D:\project\my-project\"
set name=my-project
set backup="D:\backup\project\"
set folder="D:\dev\project\my-project"
REM If you don't want to include the folder in backup file, add "\" at the end of the directory in folder param

REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files. Change if location is different
REM ---------------------- WinRAR Directory ------------------------------------
set path="C:\Progra~2\WinRAR\WinRAR.Exe";%path%
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM change working dir to dir specified above
cd %dir%

REM Replace space in hour with zero if it's less than 10
SET hr=%time:~0,2%
IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%

REM This sets the date like this: mm-dd-yr-hhmmssss (includes 1/100 secs)
Set TODAY=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%^%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%

echo Folder to compress in *.RAR format:
echo %folder%
echo.
echo.

echo Compress all files in dir and subdirs into a single archive
echo.
echo.

echo Today's date and time will be added to the base filename

rar a -r -ep1 %backup%\"%name%_%today%" %folder%

pause
goto eof
endlocal

echo.
echo "Task Completed"
echo.

REM --------------------------- exit -----------------------------------------
:end
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to add this an a new answer, because based upon your more recent edit, none of your attempts at recreating the date format as a variable are necessary. All you need to do is to read and understand the options available for the `rar.exe` command line utility you are using. Those are available by using its `-?` option. e.g. `rar.exe -?`.

Based upon that information, all you need is to use its `-ag` option:

```sh
rar.exe a -agYYYY.MM.DD -ep1 "%backup%\%name%_" "%folder%"
```

The example above assumes that you have not added a backward slash or filemask to the end of the string you have assigned to `%folder%`.

If you have assigned a backward slash or filemask to the end of the string value of `%folder%` then you'd use:

```sh
rar.exe a -agYYYY.MM.DD -ep1 -r "%backup%\%name%_" "%folder%"
```

**[EDIT /]**

To incorporate the time, as in your latest submission, *(but not the pointless and unnecessary hundredths of a second)*, just expand the `-ag` option string:

```sh
rar.exe a -agMM.DD.YYYY_HHMMSS -ep1 -r "%backup%\%name%_" "%folder%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to format the `%date%` variable is not robust at all. You will end up with mangled results once you migrate this to another pc with a different locale, or if by any chance your date format is changed.

a better solution is to simply use `powershell` to format the result for you.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('powershell get-date -format "yyyy.mm.dd"') do set "today=%%i"
echo %today%
```

Answer (score 1):

If your currently reported date string when entering `echo %date%` at the Command Prompt is `dd.MM.yyyy` and you want it to be `yyyy.MM.dd`, then the following should do that:

```sh
@Set "TODAY=%DATE%"
@Set "TODAY=%TODAY:~-4%%TODAY:~-8,4%%TODAY:~-10,2%"
@Echo %TODAY%
```

However, as I've already stated in my comments, *all now incorrectly deleted, despite nothing in them being unhelpful or rude*, that will only be guaranteed to work on any computer which reports the date in a format which ends with `dd<separator>MM<separator>yyyy`. To get the date in a format which will work on any modern computer, you need to get the assistance of a built-in program or utility. Gerhard has provided a method which uses powershell.exe, so here's one which uses WMIC.exe:

```sh
@For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set strDate) 2>NUL"') Do @Set "%%G="
@For /F "EOL=L" %%G In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get LocalDateTime 2^>NUL'
) Do @For %%H In (%%~nG) Do @Set "strDateTime=%%H"
@If Not Defined strDateTime GoTo :EOF
@Set "strDate=%strDateTime:~,4%.%strDateTime:~4,2%.%strDateTime:~6,2%"
@Echo %strDate%
```

**[EDIT /]**

If your code changed your date format and defined the new string as `%TODAY%`, as in your first example command line:

```sh
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
```

And you wanted to later in your script change the hyphens in that to periods, you'd then use:

```sh
Echo %TODAY:-=.%
```

or to redifine that variable value string:

```sh
Set "TODAY=%TODAY:-=.%"
```

**[EDIT2 /]**

Adapting your latest edit, *(with all of the bloat removed)*, and my initial code above to incorporate your required TIME string and using a format like this, `yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm.ss.##`, where `##` are hundredths of a second, *(rounded down)*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "dir=D:\project\my-project"
Set "name=my-project"
Set "backup=D:\backup\project"
Set "folder=D:\dev\project\my-project"
Set "RarPath=C:\Program Files\WinRAR"

CD /D "%dir%" 2>NUL || Exit /B 1

Set "}="
For /F "EOL=L" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get LocalDateTime 2^>NUL') Do For /F %%H In ("%%G") Do Set "}=%%H"
If Not Defined } Exit /B 1

%RarPath%\rar.exe a -ep1 -r "%backup%\%name%_%}:~,4%.%}:~4,2%.%}:~6,2%_%}:~8,2%.%}:~10,2%.%}:~12,5%" "%folder%"
Pause
Exit /B 0
```